# permission to *github repository* denied to dtrain22. error 403

Tags: git, github

I keep getting this error on a machine im using when pushing a new project to master. 
the error says:

```
permission to izzy2517/groupApp.git denied to dtrain22. 
Fatal: unable to access "git repository" the requested URL returned error 403.
```

I've tried checking my keychain, and my password wasn't stored in the Mac OS keychain helper. I tried deleting the git repository and initializing a new one. I also tried pushing something on a different machine into the same repository and it worked? I've looked at so many answers, I don't know what more to do.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your URL.

If it starts with `ssh://git@` or `git@...`, it is an SSH one, and no amount of keychain helper (used for caching credentials -- username/password -- for *HTTPS* URL) would help.

If the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is a private key authenticating dtrain22, that would explain why you see the message.